# nHibernate Linq join support; The method Join is not implemented

Tags: .net, sql, linq, nhibernate, join

I am using the latest nHibernate.Linq 2.1.2. But if I use join in my linq query I will get run time error

> "The method Join is not implemented"

Is `join` supported by nHibernate.Linq and if it is supported what is the cause of this error?

Comment: That is actually the "old and obsolete" NHibernate Linq provider.  NHibernate 3.0 (currently Alpha 2) has a new, integrated Linq provider with more sophisticated join support.  I believe you can do some joins with the older Linq provider (the one you are currently using), but the join support is limited.

Comment: Link: http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/82cd3c3dfb60befd?fwc=1 - Tuna Toksoz was one of the main authors of the 2.1.2 NH Linq provider

Comment: 2.1.2 is not maintained anymore. The NH team has decided a while ago to focus all development in the 3.x branch. This has created the awkward situation where NH3 has not been officially released yet there are no updates to 2.x, but this should be solved before the end of the year.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method join is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824172/method-join-is-not-implemented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like Joins are supported in the current version of Linq to Hibernate.

[See post from Adam Aldrich's Blog here](http://guildsocial.web703.discountasp.net/dasblogce/2009/07/29/LinqToNHibernateJoins.aspx)

I worked around it using two linq queries within my session. The first one selected from the one table and the second from the second table using the values of the first result to constrain my query. Not as efficient as a Join, but since the data I was using was minimal, it worked fine.

You could also try using the Criteria API or HQL.

Comment: Tnx Dion. I've seen that page. But how about this page http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/sstrong/archive/2009/12/16/823.aspx. Here there are examples for join and I it dates back to Dec 2009 when 2.1.2 is released. Any ideas?

Comment: The same link in nhforge http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/16/linq-to-nhibernate-progress-report-a-christmas-gift.aspx

Comment: Ok, I think I got the point. We cannot "join across entities that are NOT related".